# Can spontaneous symmetry breaking (SSB) be proven within field theory?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, symmetry-breaking

Let's consider symmetry breaking strictly within the scope of quantum field theory. QFT textbooks mainly describe the machinery of working in symmetry-broken (or unbroken!) phases: path integral formalism, computing loop corrections, renormalization...

For example, if I am interested in symmetry-broken phase of a real $\phi^4$ theory, I can go to Chapters 30-31 of Srednicki's book, and read about computing this or that quantity.

However, I am curious about the following:
Can I *prove* symmetry breaking from QFT calculations? In other words, can I calculate something that would tell me: "Look, this means that symmetry breaking does occur, in particular the expectation value of the field $\langle\phi\rangle\neq0$, and so you can proceed by assuming that $\langle\phi\rangle$ roughly equals its classical value, and follow the textbook calculations"?

The reason for asking this is that, it seems to me,

1. in path integral formalism of QFT, we have to assume certain things, such as the value of $\langle\phi\rangle$, e.g. $\langle\phi\rangle=0$, or $\langle\phi\rangle\neq0$, and then everything that follows relies on our initial assumption, and, very related,
2. perturbative expansion in interaction constant sort-of makes sure we do not stray too far from the corresponding free field theory, so e.g. by assuming we already are in a symmetry-broken phase, it does not seem credible to prove something to the effect of: "oops, our initial assumption $\langle\phi\rangle\neq0$ was wrong"; all we'll ever get are perturbative corrections in powers of interaction constant (that's assumed to be small).

In the following, I demonstrate what I want to know using a simple 1D integral:
The analogue of action is

$S = \pm\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{gx^4}{24}$

and the partition function is

$Z = \int\exp(-S)\,\mathrm{d}x$

My point is: I can perfectly well perform a perturbative expansion in $g$, I can even introduce "counter-terms" if I have a reason for it. In particular, I can proceed to treat the case

$S = -\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{gx^4}{24}$

*as if* it exhibits symmetry breaking (a patently absurd scenario for a simple 1D integral), make a substitution $x = \sqrt{\frac{6}{g}}+y$, and rewrite the "action" in terms of the new variable $y$:

$S = y^2 + \sqrt{\frac{g}{6}}y^3+\frac{gy^4}{24}$ + g-dependent const.

Now, if I treat the new action perturbatively and calculate everything in powers of $\sqrt{g}$, I will never see that actually, there is no "symmetry breaking"; but instead all my corrections will vanish with $\sqrt{g}\to0$, e.g. I will have $\langle x\rangle \approx \sqrt{\frac{6}{g}}$

So, I am coming to conclusion that, probably, one cannot *prove* symmetry breaking just from field theory alone. Am I wrong? If so, I'd be grateful if someone pointed me towards the relevant ideas / literature.

Thanks! And I am sorry if my question sounds naive for those who study the topics of phase transitions and field theory professionally, especially if it already has been asked and answered in some form.